# Why is only part of my code functioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

One part of this code is working and the other is not. I am unable to figure out the problem myself...

This is my external.js

```
var framevar = document.getElementById("userframe");
var frametogg = false;
var framesel = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#filestext').click(function(){
        if(framevar.src != "test.txt"){
            framevar.src = "test.txt";
        }
        if((frametogg === false) && (framesel === false)){
            $('#userframe').show(350);
            frametogg = true;
            $('#frameselection').show(350);
            framesel = true;
        }else if(frametogg === false){
            $('#userframe').show(350);
            frametogg = true;
        }else if(framesel === false){
            $('#frameselection').show(350);
            framesel = true;
        }else{
            $('#userframe').hide(350);
            frametogg = false;
            $('#frameselection').hide(350);
            framesel = false;
        }
    });

    $('#uploadtext').click(function(){
        if(framevar.src != "uploadpage.php"){
            framevar.src = "uploadpage.php";
        }
        if(frametogg === false){
            $('#userframe').show(350);
            frametogg = true;
        }else if((frametogg === true) && (framesel === false)){
            $('#userframe').hide(350);
            frametogg = false;
        }
        if(framesel === true){
            $('#frameselection').hide(350);
            framesel = false;
        }
    });

    $('#entryloggertitle').click(function(){ 
        $('#entrylogger').toggle(350);
    });
});
```

And this is my home.php

```
<div id="filesdiv">
<iframe id="userframe" src="uploadpage.php"></iframe>
<select id="frameselection" multiple>
<script>selectionTable();</script>
</select></div>

<span id="entryloggertitle">log.</span><br/>
<span id="filestext">files</span><br/>
<span id="uploadtext">upload</span><br/>

<div id="entrylogger">
<form action="add.php" method="POST">
    p? <input type="checkbox" name="public[]" value="yes" checked/>
    <input type="text" name="entry" size="12"/>
    <input type="submit" value="push!" style="display:none;" />
</form>
</div>
```

In the css file, *entrylogger*, *frameselection* and *userframe* has the display:none. I only put the relevant part of the code.

The toggle function of *entrylogger* works just fine. But I don't understand why the toggle of *userframe* and *frameselection* isn't working.

Comment: What is the desired functionality? Is the userframe supposed to be hidden on initial page load and then display when they click the files text?

Comment: @MrMadsen On the execution the frame should be invisible. It should be displayed when the person clicks on either of the links. Frame selection item should be only displayed when the files text is clicked. And when the person re-clicks on either, frame should disappear.

Comment: It seems to be working in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u3bk7fvk/ unless I'm misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: No, @MrMadsen you got it all alright. I also copied my code there, the whole code and it worked out just fine. My problem it seems was to include external javascript in the head, instead of the foot. But when I include it at the end of the body functions like selectionTable(); doesn't work. Is there a way to handle them both using one external sheet or should I just separate the sheets?

Comment: Include them in the correct order so that `<script>selectionTable();</script>` occurs AFTER the script that declares selectionTable()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my code is in perfect condition (well, not perfect but it checks out) for it to do the trick I want it to do. My problem, it seems was to include the external javascript sheet in the head of the page. Although this doesn't answer how one part was functioning and the other wasn't, I think I can figure something out from now on. Thank you all for your participation in my humble question.

Answer (score 1):

In this **if** statement,

```
    if((frametogg === false) && (framesel === false)){
        $('#userframe').show(350);
        frametogg = true;
        $('#frameselection').show(350);
        framesel = true;
```

you're saying to show the userframe and frame selection only if frametogg and framese1 are false, which is the case when the page loads because both values are set to false at the top. However, you said that on execution you want them to be invisible, so the code for the userframe and frame selection here should be using the hide method.

Comment: But that if condition happens when I click on the files text. I mean, they will become visible once the person clicks on the text and not directly.